# Insides of __getattr__(self, __getitem__) in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python2, this old-style class:

```
class C:
    x = 'foo'
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print name
        print type(name)
        return getattr(self.x, name)

> X = C()
> X[1]
__getitem__
<type 'str'>
'o'
```

Question is, what is going on in the bowels of this? More specifically, if `name` is just a string, how is the index `1` stored so that `getattr` knows that it has to call `__getitem__(1)` to retrieve the character `o`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cut right to it, this is what is happening step by step.

When you call `X[1]`, it is going to attempt to look up an attribute called `__getitem__` in your class. As you do not have any attributes (function or variable) with that name, so it will fallback to call your `__getattr__` method with the name of the attribute (`__getitem__`) it is requesting. This name is always a string.

When you do a `"return getattr(self.x, name)"` what you are actually doing is returning the `__getitem__` method of "foo" ie: `"foo".__getitem__` which then is called with the argument 1: `"foo".__getitem__(1)` which is the same as `"foo"[1]` which returns you the first "o".

Comment: +1 Note that this only applies to "old style" classes in python2, for "new style" classes extending `object` `__getitem__` is not looked up using `__getattr__`

Comment: Thanks, but I understand this. What you say is the only thing that can be happening. What I want to understand is where is the index `1` stored so that when you get to calling `"foo"__getitem__`, that is the index that is passed. I don't understand this, given that inside `__getattr__`, `__getitem__` is only a string. I don't know if I'm making myself clear.

Comment: My question applies to "new style" classes as well, btw, if you just replace `X[1]` above by `X.__getitem__(1)`

Comment: When you call special operators such as `[ ]`, Python has special handling to interpret this as a funcation call with the argument of whatever is between the [ and ]. This is the same if this was a dictionary or any object that implements a `__getitem__` method. You are returning a reference to a function inside `__getattr__`, which is what it needs to then call it with the 1 argument. There is no storage for the 1 when calling `__getattr__` as it has not even gotten to that stage of the even using that value yet, not until the your return from `__getattr__`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you please be more precise? 1.- "...Python has special handling to interpret this as a funcation call with the argument of whatever is between the [ and ]... " What you are saying here is that `[x]` is equivalent to `__getitem__(x)`, correct? I understand this. 2.- "...You are returning a reference to a function inside `__getattr__`, which is what it needs to then call it with the 1 argument..." I got lost. When you say "You..." do you mean, the `__getattr__` method?

Comment: Yes on number 1. Number 2, yes the `__getattr__` is returning a function in this example. If you call `getattr (X.x, "__getitem__")` it will result in "foo"'s getitem method. Python then takes it and calls it with 1. When I say "you" I mean that it is your code that is returning the function in `__getattr__`